# Favicons in HTML Templates

Tags: html, css, favicon

I used a HTML free template from Colorlib.com. I gave them recognition and put copyright at the bottom of my site. However, I want to change the favicon to my own (they made their own, but I want to use mine). I got rid of the favicon image and replaced it with mine but even after committing changes and deploying, it shows the previous favicon. How is this possible? It's not even in the folder... How can I fix this?

Github: https://github.com/Ispeeta/Connect-to-Change/tree/master/img/core-img (this is where I kept my favicon, the previous one on my site was a "K" but I want to have a maple leaf)

Site: https://connect2change.netlify.app/stories

Comment: have you cleared your cache? Ctrl F5

Comment: it is showing maple leaf on my end, you should be fine. its just a cache issue i believe

Comment: Its all working fine on my end as well. Please clear cache or your chrome incongnito browser to see changes you have added. It should show maple leaf as you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear your cache to fix the problem.